# How to calculate control points for cubic curve, which approximates an elliptic arc?

Tags: geometry, vector-graphics, bezier, elliptic-curve

Almost all vector graphics applications (like Corel) approximate elliptic arcs with several cubic Bezier curves. I need to add similar functionality to my application. So my question is: how to calculate control points of that Bezier curve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [lots of pages](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=approximate+ellipse+bezier) explaining how to do this. [This paper](http://www.tinaja.com/glib/ellipse4.pdf) by Don Lancaster, for example, gives control parameters for divisions of an ellipse into between 2 and 8 cubic splines, with a detailed analysis of the 4-spline case.